# Why does ml-engine restart my job multiple times?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I started to use GCP ml-engine to train neural networks. When I was checking for a particular job through tensorboard, it showed the following graph for the loss (plotted vs wall time):
[image: loss plotted vs wall time]

Checking the log in the stackdriver for a time slot in which the "raise" occurs, I found the following:
[image: screenshot from stack-driver log]

It seems to me, that the job was re-initialized. The reason is completely unclear to me. Any explanations/help would be appreciated!

Additional information: The particular job, where I observed this behavior, run in parallel to other jobs. The other jobs terminated as expected. The sole difference between the jobs was the number of hidden layers in the Neural Network being 2 whereas in the other jobs being 1 and 4.

Comment: It might be the case that the job was unlucky that it got scheduled on a VM that GCE decided to restart for maintenance, but maintenance should not happen multiple times in a row. Can you share the project and job id with cloudml-feedback@google.com so that we can inspect the logs to figure out the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Estimators API what TensorFlow is doing is the following:

1. Open a session (`tf.Session()`), load graph for training and checkpoints(if any) and train for X steps.
2. Save checkpoint and summaries for tensorboard.
3. Close session
4. Open a session, load graph for evaluation and evaluate eval set
5. Save summaries for tensorboard.
6. Close session
7. Repeat 1-6 until stopping criteria is met.

That is why you are seeing this kind of re-initialization.